# Lawnmower cut-out and I reckon something has blown (pics inside)

Tags: electrical, lawn-mower

Long story short, my Flymo lawnmower was exposed to rain over the winter period. When Spring came, it started up. However, I realised that I needed more slack on the cable and turned it off (there was a gentle pull against the cable when this occurred). However, when I tried to turn it back on, it wouldn't start. I replaced the cable and it still isn't working. Today, I opened the switch housing and this is what I saw:

The capacitor:

[image]

This doesn't look good?

[image]

Another shot:

[image]

The entire switch:

[image]

Any idea what might be the issue? Should I just replace the switch?

Comment: the yellow thing is a .22 micro fared capacitor. This gives the electric motor the phase shift to get the motor going some times the caps go bad (short out) and pop, this is what I think happened but it could just be a bad connection hard to tell from the photos, a bad cap or a bad connection to the cap would keep the motor from running.

Comment: A capacitor like that would be sold at Mouser Electronics, Digi-Key, or possibly Galco.